# Google Sheet SUMIFS formula returning 0?

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I have a SUMIFS formula in Google Sheets which is the following:

=SUMIFS('AWIN MASTER'!$AW:$AW,'AWIN MASTER'!$AT:$AT,">=" &A101,'AWIN MASTER'!$AT:$AT,"<" &A102)

This formula is the sum of a cost on another sheet, when the date is between two dates on the current sheet.

which is returning 0 when it shouldn't... it's working for my other formula but not mine... Could someone help please?

Comment: Could you please attach (a copy of) the Google Sheet: this is very unclear and difficult to follow without any supporting information.

Comment: I second taylor.2317. Keep in mind that we cannot see your spreadsheet, layout, data, data types, ranges, etc., and we don't know your end goal. Most often, the most efficient means of sharing is via a link to the spreadsheet (or to a copy of it).

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FILTER('AWIN MASTER'!AW:AW; 
                    'AWIN MASTER'!AT:AT >= A101;
                    'AWIN MASTER'!AT:AT <  A102)))
```

or see if you got the right conditions:

```
=FILTER('AWIN MASTER'!AW:AW; 
        'AWIN MASTER'!AT:AT >= A101;
        'AWIN MASTER'!AT:AT <  A102)
```

Comment: I have found that the issue was due to a formatting issue from IMPORTRANGE - the original formula worked then.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was because of formatting through IMPORTRANGE

Thank you all for your help!